# White notification icon for Android with Phonegap Build and PushPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, build, notifications, icons

I'm messing around with Phonegap using Adobe's Build service and I was wondering if (and if so, how) I could make my notifications display a white icon (as Google describes [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)). I'm using the [PushPlugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324) but I couldn't find any documentation on this. At the moment my app just displays the launcher icon next to the notification content.

So does anyone know if there's some way to enable an alternate notification icon with the PushPlugin, am I stuck with the launcher icon or is there another plugin with this feature?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The new "[phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md)" plugin has excellent support for notification icons for the new Lollipop.

Build an icon that has color on a transparent icon first.  Per google's [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html) all notifications will display white on the notification tray.

So build the icon and then specify it as follows.  "icon" specifies the image.

Place copies of "myicon" with appropriate resolutions in /platforms/android/res/drawable-RES/ folders as follows:

```
   mdpi    - 22x22 area in 24x24
   hdpi    - 33x33 area in 36x36
   xhdpi   - 44x44 area in 48x48
   xxhdpi  - 66x66 area in 72x72
   xxxhdpi - 88x88 area in 96x96
```

Now in your JS, specify your icon.  The "iconColor" is optional and will specify the background when you swipe down.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "<<SENDER_ID>>",
        "icon": "myicon",
        "iconColor": "#123456"
    },
```

In your push payload you can now-override the icon that is specified on swipe down by adding an "image" parameter.  Image can either be a resource, it can reference "www/image/image.png", or can be a full URL.

The "[plugin docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md)" are excellent, I recommend reading them.   Hope this is useful to somebody.

Answer (score 16):

I have never used Phonegap build - I do the build process manually on my machine. Anyway, I think you should find the GCMIntentService.java file under src/com/plugin/gcm. In that file, search for the following line of code:

```
.setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
```

This may be replaced by the icon you want. If you place an icon named "notification.png" in the /res/drawable folder, you could change the code line to:

```
.setSmallIcon(your.package.name.R.drawable.notification);
```

Comment: Where would the /res/drawable folder be?

Comment: When building this with the modification you suggested, I'm getting

platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                            
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable notification
  location: class drawable

Would you know why that might be?

Answer (score 10):

Set this on your PhoneGap or Cordova **config.xml**

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>
```

Comment: This is a very hacky solution and not very future proof.  It'll work now but specifically excludes Lollipop from your build.

Comment: But Google has restricted to use minimum target SDK version >= 26 then how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is for the new plugin - [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

Might work for the old PushPlugin as well.

Android has set guidelines for the notification icon for Lollipop and above. The icon needs to be purely white and transparent.

What I did:

1. Generated different sizes for my logo image (lets name it "notif.png") which had transparent back, using this [tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example). Remember to have a transparent back image, if you dont have a transparent image, android will just show white icon only. Lets assume the generated icon's name is "ic_notif".
2. Copy the respective size images to res/drawables folder.
3. In the push JS code, give the value "ic_notif" to "icon" property. And "grey" to "iconColor" property like this: `PushNotification.init({"android":{"senderId":"XX","icon":"ic_notif","iconColor":"grey"}});`

Test your notification using this [tool](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info).

Answer (score 1):

Android API 21+ uses only white color for small icon.
Changing target SDK Version makes your compiler to use elder SDK so U`ll be cut in new SDK features.
So the best way is to have two icons: small and big one (when bar is dragged down)

Answer (score 0):

For a time, you can set your android-targetSdkVersion to API 20.
This version don't use the new features, that broke the old resources.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution works when combining two answers from here:

First I set the target sdk version

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>
```

And then I edited the plugin code as suggested here, in **GCMIntentService** class I modified the **setNotificationSmallIcon** method to be:

```
 private void setNotificationSmallIcon(Context context, Bundle extras, String packageName, Resources resources, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, String localIcon) {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().icon);
}
```

or if you want to set a custom icon then use

```
 private void setNotificationSmallIcon(Context context, Bundle extras, String packageName, Resources resources, NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, String localIcon) {
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(<your.package.name>.R.drawable.<notification-drawable-name>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced too many problem in this but after searching all over the  internet i found different solutions for this issue.Let me sum up all the solutions and explain:

Note:This solution is for Phonegap cordova users

1. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCdjq.png)

`<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20"/>`

You need to set your android-targetSdkVersion value to less than 21.
 So after setting this value Notification icon image will appear till Android      6(Marshmallow), It won't work in Android 7(Nougat).
This solution worked for me.

2. Change the statusbarStyle in your config file.
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTovp.png)

`<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />`

But this solution will work only when your app is opened.
So, I guess this solution is not the best solution but it worked for many users.

3. Make your icon transparent.
   This solution worked for many people.
   Actually the thing is, In the development of Native aplication we need to provide them three images:
   (a)App icon 
   (b)Notification icon 
   (c)Status bar icon image, but in case of Hybrid mobile application development there is no option to do so.
   So make your icon transparent and this solution will solve your problem.

And I am sure one of the above solution will work for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the recent update to PhoneGap Builder to version 2 (and CLI v7.0.1), I'm now able to get white notification icons to appear correctly with cordova-plugin-push.

I first created my .png icons (with transparency) in GIMP. I then put them in my project at `/www/res/notify_icon/android/`

Here are the relevant excerpts of my config.xml file:

```
<widget id="com.myapp.app" version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
    <preference name="pgb-builder-version" value="2" />

    ...

    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" spec="~2.0.0-rc5">
        <param name="SENDER_ID" value="1xxxxxxxxxx0" />
    </plugin>

    ...

    <platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-36-ldpi.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/notify_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-48-mdpi.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/notify_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-72-hdpi.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/notify_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-96-xhdpi.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/notify_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-144-xxhdpi.png" target="res/drawable-xxhdpi/notify_icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="www/res/notify_icon/android/notify_icon-192-xxxhdpi.png" target="res/drawable-xxxhdpi/notify_icon.png" />

        ...

    </platform>
</widget>
```

Here is the where I initialize push:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {

        var push_options = {
            android: {
                senderID: "1xxxxxxxxxxx0",
                sound: true,
                vibrate: true,
                icon:  'notify_icon',
                iconColor: '#66CC00'
            },
            browser: {},
            ios: {
                senderID: "1xxxxxxxxxxx0",
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true
            },
            windows: {}
        };

        var push = PushNotification.init(push_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to the change the

> android-targetSdkVersion

in your config.xml file.

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="20" />
```

**20** android sdk version support the logo in Android. So you have to change the android sdk version in your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using [Build's](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324) [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin); local modifications to `.setSmallIcon()`<sup>[#100](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/93067b9303252d5ed7394819bf220db56d99d22c/src/android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java#L100)</sup> will be lost.

Unless you build locally or use an alternative GCM plugin, you're restricted to modifying:

```
title    extras.getString("title")
message  extras.getString("message")
msgcnt   extras.getString("msgcnt")
```