# Push notification shows default icon instead of the icon I setup in cordova config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

I have a ionic project in which I have set config.xml for android as follows

```
<icon src="src/res/icon/android/notification.png" />
<icon src="src/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
<icon src="src/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
<icon src="src/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
<icon src="src/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
```

After running ionic build android, I see the res/drawable folder in my platform/android folder and it shows that notification.png is inside the drawable folder as icon.png. I am using my own fork of phonegap [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), where I have set the notification icon to icon.png as

```
import com.project.mobile.R;
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))...
```

But when I test it on my device,I still see the default icon.png icon in the push notification bar. I have also tried putting notification.png in android's res/drawable folder and changing the code for Plugin to

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
```

And it works. But I need a solution which can work where I just setup the config.xml such that I don't need to add a single file everytime I create a new build. I am using Ionic version 1.3.19 and cordova version 4.3.0. Ask any question If you need more clearification..

Comment: did you try .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon) ?

Comment: Yes I did, That also results in showing the default icon.png. I have tried cordova clean and removing the Android platform and adding it again. I took inspiration from second answer on this [notification icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596213/white-notification-icon-for-android-with-phonegap-build-and-pushplugin) question.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem...

Comment: @XavitojCheema any workaround / solution for this issue ?

Comment: @XavitojCheema did you solve this?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have not been working on this project anymore, and I have a very vague memory of what I did, but you guys can checkout the Push Notification by Ionicframework, If that works for you. :)