# Phonegap using Bluemix push don't show app icon

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ibm-cloud

I need to show my app icon in the notification bar for the push received but when I receive a push notification in the notification bar, the Android Lollipop only show a star icon instead of the app icon, but in the IOS notification bar show the correct icon of the app. I am using IBM Bluemix push notification with phonegap. My config.xml is this http://pastebin.com/bpKFn51z.

This answer [White notification icon for Android with Phonegap Build and PushPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596213/white-notification-icon-for-android-with-phonegap-build-and-pushplugin#answer-20620133) maybe work but IBM Bluemix only distribute the jar files of his API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use Cordova StatusBarNotification plugin.
Or if you want a faster solution, you can follow what is suggested in the following blog post:

http://devgirl.org/2012/10/25/tutorial-android-push-notifications-with-phonegap/